# Declare Global variables in background of feature-karate Soap API

Tags: karate

I am using karate for SOAP API services. How can I declare a global variable ?? as you can see in below feature file? after print response I have variable name `def ourSession = /Envelope/Body/LoginReturn` I am using this variable (`ourSession`) in next scenario but it's failing ? but it's not global. 
So how can I declare "ourSession" as a global variable ?? so I can use into other scenarios? 
Any help will be highly appreciated. Please have a look of my feature file below;

#

```
Feature: 
    SOAP calls to the following service:

Background:

     * url baseUrl
     * def configSS = Java.type('practice.utilities.Shellscripts')

##################################### LOG IN #########################################################
@DataAcquisition
 Scenario: login
     Given request
     """
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsh="http://www.informatica.com/wsh">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsh:Login>
         <RepositoryDomainName>Domain_Aqr_Dev_Powercenter</RepositoryDomainName>
         <RepositoryName>Powercenter_Repository_Service</RepositoryName>
         <UserName>#(AM_USERNAME)</UserName>
         <Password>#(AM_PASSWORD)</Password>
         <UserNameSpace/>
      </wsh:Login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

     """
     When soap action '/login'
     Then assert responseStatus == 200
     And print 'response: ', response
     * def ourSession = /Envelope/Body/LoginReturn
     * print ourSession
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i am using this variable (ourSession) in next scenario

You can't. There are many answers in Stack Overflow addressing this question, please find them and read them.

And please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#script-structure

To quote:

> if you are expecting a variable in the Background to be modified by one Scenario so that later ones can see the updated value - that is not how you should think of them, and you should combine your 'flow' into one scenario.

There are many ways to "re-use" in Karate such as [`call`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-other-feature-files). So you should be able to figure out how to do what you want.

Now if you really want a "global" variable, please use [`callonce`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks) that is most likely what you are looking for:

Comment: i tired using callonce but gave me an error maybe my syntax is wrong. Could you please be massive kind and advise me the correct syntax please, according to my feature file. I will much appreciate it. Like how can i use callonce using (ourSession)

Comment: Using "callonce", please correct me if i am wrong, i can use only once or i can use in multiple scenarios ??

Comment: @AzazAhmad sorry - please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 1):

Do not create a new scenario for the subsequent call. A single scenario can have multiple requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but my business requirements are to split them into different scenarios with different tags. However it works fine if i run all under one scenario using one tag